# Connected graph $G$ without bridges such that $G\!\setminus\!e$ is a tree

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

> Let $G$ be a connected graph of order $n \ge 3$ without bridges and suppose that $G\!\setminus\!e$ is a tree for every edge $e$ of the graph $G$. What is $G$? Provide a proof for your answer

My attempt:

> *Proof*: I claim that $G$ is $C_{n}$. Let $G=(V,E)$, then for all $e \in E$,  $G\!\setminus\!e$ will be $P_{n-1}$, which is a tree.

Is this correct? How can I improve it?

Comment: It is correct that a cycle has the property stated in the problem. But you also need to prove that _only_ cycles have this property.

Comment: @HenningMakholm how do I show that though?

Comment: Since there are no bridges, every edge must be in a cycle (can you show this?).  Suppose now you take a cycle in the graph.  If there is another edge, what would happen if you removed it?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments your proof only shows that all cycle graphs $C_n$ have the desired property, but you still need to prove that *only* cycle graphs have that property. The rest of your proof could look something like this:

> Suppose you have a graph $G$ that is not a cycle graph $C_n$. If $G$ is a tree then it must contain a bridge, so it cannot have the desired property. Otherwise $G$ contains a cycle and at least one edge $e$ that is not part of that cycle. Since $G\!\setminus\!e$ still has a cycle, it cannot be a tree. So only cycle graphs $C_n$ have the desired property.